# How to modify tsconfig.json through node api

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to modify the configuration content of tsconfig through nodejs. Now I have obtained the configuration of config through ts.readConfigFile, but I don't know how to modify it, such as changing the target from es6 to next. Can't use fs.outputJSONSync to modify, because I want to keep the comments in tsconfig.json

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to actually modify the file permanently, or just parse it and add your own configuration before the compilation?

Comment: I want to modify the file permanently@richbai90

Comment: CHeck out https://www.npmjs.com/package/comment-json